# javax.persistence.Query does not set parameter

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jpa-2.0, jpa-2.1

Here is the Query instance I'm executing

```
entityManager.createNativeQuery(SHIPMENTS_UNION_QUERY, RESULT_MAPPER)
                .setParameter("aggreagateCategories", aggregatePCNames)
                .setParameter("startDate", startDate)
                .setParameter("endDate", endDate)
                .setParameter("individualCategories", individualPCNames)
                .getResultList();
```

The logs for the execution of the above line are

```
12:29:36.909 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader : bindNamedParameters() 2010-01-01 -> endDate [3]
12:29:36.910 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader : bindNamedParameters() 2010-01-01 -> endDate [6]
12:29:36.910 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader : bindNamedParameters() 'AirConditioner' -> aggreagateCategories [1]
12:29:36.912 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader : bindNamedParameters() 2010-01-01 -> startDate [2]
12:29:36.912 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader : bindNamedParameters() 2010-01-01 -> startDate [5]
12:29:36.912 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader : bindNamedParameters() 'Cooler', 'Heater', 'Dryer' -> individualCategories [4]
```

When the above query is executed with the param hardcoded into the query itself, the query executed just fine and the results are fetched and mapped to the RESULT_MAPPER that corresponding to @SqlResultSetMapping, but when done so with the above setParameter statements, the execution does not retuen any results..

Please help identify the issue.

***EDIT1***

> Hardcoded Query

```
SELECT ac.category_name category_name, SUM(ais.volume) volume,   qc.date, qc.quarter as quarter, qc.year 
FROM actual_industry_shipment ais 
JOIN quarter_calendar qc ON ais.quarter=qc.id  
JOIN product_category pc ON ais.product_category_id=pc.id 
JOIN aggregated_product_categories ac ON ac.id = pc.aggregate_category_id 
WHERE ac.category_name IN ('AirConditioner') 
AND qc.date BETWEEN  '2010-01-01' AND '2011-01-01' 
GROUP BY pc.aggregate_category_id, qc.quarter, qc.year 
UNION 
SELECT pc.category_name category_name, ais.volume volume,   qc.date, qc.quarter as quart, qc.year 
FROM actual_industry_shipment ais  
JOIN quarter_calendar qc ON ais.quarter=qc.id  
JOIN product_category pc ON ais.product_category_id=pc.id 
WHERE pc.category_name IN ('Dryer', 'Cooler') 
AND qc.date BETWEEN  '2010-01-01' AND '2011-01-01'
```

> Query with params

```
SELECT ac.category_name category_name, SUM(ais.volume) volume,   qc.date, qc.quarter as quarter, qc.year 
FROM actual_industry_shipment ais 
JOIN quarter_calendar qc ON ais.quarter=qc.id
JOIN product_category pc ON ais.product_category_id=pc.id
JOIN aggregated_product_categories ac ON ac.id = pc.aggregate_category_id 
WHERE ac.category_name IN (?) 
AND qc.date BETWEEN  ? AND ? 
GROUP BY pc.aggregate_category_id, qc.quarter, qc.year
UNION 
SELECT pc.category_name category_name, ais.volume volume,   qc.date, qc.quarter as quart, qc.year 
FROM actual_industry_shipment ais  
JOIN quarter_calendar qc ON ais.quarter=qc.id  
JOIN product_category pc ON ais.product_category_id=pc.id 
WHERE pc.category_name IN (?) 
AND qc.date BETWEEN  ? AND ?
```

> Native Query that is declared in the code

```
private static final String SHIPMENTS_UNION_QUERY =
        "SELECT ac.category_name category_name, SUM(ais.volume) volume,   qc.date, qc.quarter as quarter, qc.year " +
                "FROM actual_industry_shipment ais " +
                "JOIN quarter_calendar qc " +
                "ON ais.quarter=qc.id  " +
                "JOIN product_category pc " +
                "ON ais.product_category_id=pc.id " +
                "JOIN aggregated_product_categories ac " +
                "ON ac.id = pc.aggregate_category_id " +
                "WHERE " +
                "ac.category_name IN (:aggreagateCategories) " +
                "AND qc.date BETWEEN  :startDate AND :endDate " +
                "GROUP BY " +
                "pc.aggregate_category_id, qc.quarter, qc.year " +

                "UNION " +

                "SELECT pc.category_name category_name, ais.volume volume,   qc.date, qc.quarter as quart, qc.year " +
                "FROM actual_industry_shipment ais  " +
                "JOIN quarter_calendar qc " +
                "ON ais.quarter=qc.id  " +
                "JOIN product_category pc " +
                "ON ais.product_category_id=pc.id " +
                "WHERE pc.category_name IN (:individualCategories) " +
                "AND qc.date BETWEEN  :startDate AND :endDate";
```

Comment: Can you add the code for SHIPMENTS_UNION_QUERY as well which is causing the issue ?

Comment: Please post the Query you try to execute.

Comment: Found the problem, I have been sending the parameter to IN clause as a quoted text instead of List in the setParameter, but which is supported only in Hibernate

Answer (score 0):

The named params query is NOT the exactly same as the original Hard coded Native SQL Query, you can look below (taken only the differed section of the query):

**Parameter Query:**

```
category_name, ais.volume volume,   qc.date, 
qc.quarter as quart, qc.year FROM 
actual_industry_shipment ais  
JOIN quarter_calendar qc ON
```

**Hard coded Query:**

```
ais.quarter=qc.id  JOIN category_name, 
ais.volume volume,  product_category pc ON ais.product_category_id=pc.id WHERE 
pc.category_name IN ('Dryer', 'Cooler') AND qc.date 
BETWEEN  '2010-01-01' AND '2011-01-01'
```

Comment: I'm using the named parameter, adding one more update

Comment: JPA does not require the implementations to support named parameters in native queries, but Hibernate does it as a bonus feature. It won't work if OP switches to EclipseLink, but this is not the problem.

Comment: @coladict tried with positional paramters too, didn't work either

Comment: The Hibernate generated query (with params) is NOT the exactly same as the original Native SQL Query, r u sure that u r using the same query in both ?

Comment: @javaguy I see the named parameters are converted to ? for prepared statement, is there anything else you find that is different

Comment: Are you sure that u r using the same query in runs (except removal of hard codings) ?

Comment: @SomasundaramSekar please revisit your query, i have put some concern in my following answer.

Answer (score 0):

Your date parameter are not bound as String as your hard coded query seems to be and which is working, Also same date is applied in both start and end date different from hard coded query.

```
12:29:36.909 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader : bindNamedParameters() 2010-01-01 -> endDate [3]
12:29:36.910 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader : bindNamedParameters() 2010-01-01 -> endDate [6]
12:29:36.910 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader : bindNamedParameters() 'AirConditioner' -> aggreagateCategories [1]
12:29:36.912 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader : bindNamedParameters() 2010-01-01 -> startDate [2]
12:29:36.912 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader : bindNamedParameters() 2010-01-01 -> startDate [5]
12:29:36.912 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader : bindNamedParameters() 'Cooler', 'Heater', 'Dryer' -> individualCategories [4]
```

Your query which is working has dates in quotes,

```
BETWEEN  '2010-01-01' AND '2011-01-01'
```

Comment: You ALMOST had it. He's binding the same date to both startDate and endDate. My colleague did the same thing, not realising that he has to use a new `java.util.Date` object for setting both parameters, instead of reusing it and calling `setYear` or whichever OP is using. What he did was `Date endDate = startDate; endDate.setMonth(...);` then bind it. I think my OP must have done the same, not realizing that endDate and startDate are the same object, not copies of each-other.

Answer (score 0):

This is where we see the problem:

```
12:29:36.909 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader : bindNamedParameters() 2010-01-01 -> endDate [3]
12:29:36.910 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader : bindNamedParameters() 2010-01-01 -> endDate [6]
12:29:36.910 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader : bindNamedParameters() 'AirConditioner' -> aggreagateCategories [1]
12:29:36.912 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader : bindNamedParameters() 2010-01-01 -> startDate [2]
12:29:36.912 DEBUG org.hibernate.loader.Loader : bindNamedParameters() 2010-01-01 -> startDate [5]
```

You are binding the same date on both.
I'm guessing your code looks something like:

```
Date endDate = getDateParameter(...);
Date startDate = endDate;
startDate.setYear(endDate.getYear()-1);
```

The problem with that is that `startDate` and `endDate` are not copies of each-other, but are the same exact object. When you change the date on startDate, you've changed it on endDate.
You should copy it like this:

```
Date startDate = new Date(endDate.getTime());
```

Comment: I dont think that is the problem, the date works fine as a string as I have given, even between the same date.